# Проверка Edit на наличее недопустимых символов Delphi

Tags: delphi

Есть регистрационная форма в которой находится два Edit и Button. Нужно, чтобы при вводе буквы, сразу же проверяло допустимый это символ, или нет. Допустимые символы для данной программы (Разделеные запятой): Английские буквы, цифры, нижнее подчеркивание (_), точка (.). Максимальное количество символов в Edit - 15 символов.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос. Следует добавить, в чем у вас возникли затруднения и что, как вы пробовали сделать (понятно, что безрезультатно), чтобы выполнить задачу.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Много способов в зависимости насколько ты презираешь try..except..finally, еще можно это сделать процедурой с отправкой переменных и ее сохранением. OnДействие... Но проще скопипастить 2 раза на каждое поле.

```
ch: char;
s:string;
//бла-бла-бла
Ловим ch:=KeyPress();
сase ch of
A..z и т.д.: 
  if проверка длины s <= length(edit1.text) then s:=s+конвертация(ch) edit1.text:=s; else чот другое ;
else ch:=#0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Назначить обработчик Edit1.OnKeyPress

```
procedure TMainForm.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (ord (Key) >= 32) then
    if not (char (Key) in ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9',
      '_', ',']) or (length ((Sender as TEdit).Text) >= 15) then
      Key := #0;
end;
```

Но отлавливать нажатия клавиш мало, могут вставить из буфера обмена.
Вы же не хотите писать новые компонент-наследник от TEdit или возится с SetWindowsHookEx?

Поэтому я бы на вашем месте не заморачивался, а давал бы вводить как есть и проверял бы 1 раз перед использованием.

Уточните, как глубоко вы готовы пойти.